# Using Guid.Empty.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in a library which returns Guid. So my code looks something like this:

```
var UnqId = myMethod();
```

myMethod returns Guid.

I have an existing code further as below:

```
if (Guid.Empty.ToString != UnqId)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

I want to know what is the use of Guid.Empty.ToString(), when the above code can be written in this way:

```
if (UnqId.ToString() != String.Empty())
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

Is there any specific use of Guid.Empty.ToString() ?

Comment: Guid.Empty is not the same as String.Empty

Comment: You should use `if(UnqId == default(Guid)){}`

Comment: Why the string conversion? Just `if(UniqueId != Guid.Empty)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter What is the use of default ?

Comment: @RKh: it returns an instance of `Guid`, the default is the same as `Guid.Empty`. So you could also use `if(UnqId == Guid.Empty){}`. My point is: don't compare strings when you want to compare Guids.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @RKh [default value expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions)` return the default value of that type, which for reference types is `null` and for a `Guid` is `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: `return UnqId != Guid.Empty;` is all you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Guid.Empty.ToString()` is not the empty string it will be this : `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. So the checkings if `UnqId` is the empty GUID string

Comment: When using: if(UnqId != default(Guid)){}, it is throwing warning: "!= operand cannot be applied for string and Guid.

Comment: @RKh, well the `UndId` is a string not a GUID, why this is you should ask the writer of `myMethod`, my guess is that the results comes from doing a `ToString()` on a GUID. You can't compare `string` and `GUID` with `==` you need to convert either `string` to `GUID`, or as in your code, convert `GUID` to `string`

Comment: So then that means `myMethod` is returning a `string` then, because `default(Guid)` definitely returns a `Guid`. Maybe don't use `var` if you're not sure what the return type is.